# Set custom meta tags in a WordPress Post using WPAPI

Tags: node.js, wordpress, wp-api

I'v been trying to figure out how to set meta tags using the Node JS [WPAPI](http://wp-api.org/node-wpapi/using-the-client/) (which feels outdataed) WP library, but cant get it working.

For example, how would you add the `<meta property="description" content="content" />` tag to the HTML of a WordPress Post programmatically using WPAPI or the WP Rest API?

Here is some code, which creates the post successfully, but no new meta tags are added to the HTML when I inspect the post:

```
const postOptions = {
    title: "Post Title",
    content: "<h1>Heading</h1>",
    status: "draft",
    meta: {
         description: 'A discription',
    }
}
const client = new WPAPI(config);
const post = client.posts().create(postOptions);
```